# What is the most advantageous starting equipment for the Magicka: Vietnam rescue mission?

Tags: magicka

At time of writing, there are five starting outfits for Magicka. Since hats and robes have no effect and you'll drop your sword for a firearm early in the Magicka: Vietnam rescue mission, only the staff really matters. Which of these five is best for the Vietnam rescue mission?

- Basic Staff (Default, no bonus)
- Staff +1 (Wizard Hat DLC, +1 damage)
- Bug Staff (Mea Culpa DLC, summons bugs)
- Patriot Staff (Magicka: Vietnam DLC, throws grenades)
- Staff of Endurance (Magicka: Nippon DLC, grants "increased resistance")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Patriot Staff** is pretty much objectively the best choice. The grenades do decent damage, and you can even push them closer to your enemies (by casting empty). All other starting staves aren't all that useful.

- The *Basic Staff* has no bonus at all, of course, so it's disqualified.
- The *Staff +1*'s attack bonus is laughably low (literally doing just 1 extra damage), and it provides no other advantages.
- The *Bug Staff*'s active ability is pretty much useless in any context. The summoned bugs do low damage, can get in your and your teammates' way (damaging you), have a short summoning reach and are very slow. It's doubly useless in the Vietnam DLC, where all the enemies use ranged attacks.
- In terms of general usefulness, the *Staff of Endurance* would come in at a close second; however, if there's one thing you're not up against in the Rescue Mission, it's elemental effects.

Comment: Is it certain that the Staff of Endurance's benefit only applies to elemental effects and not bullets?

Comment: @JonathanDrain The [Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/73031 "Magicka: Nippon on Steam")'s wording is pretty unambiguous, IMO.